# Handsontable increase row header width

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I'm using *custom row header names* and there is one that happens to be a little longer than others.

```
rowHeaders: ["Entree", "", "Plat", "", "Dessert", "", "Prix 2", "Prix 3"]
```

My question is how do I increase the `row header width`?

I have thoroughly checked the documentation without luck.

[image: t missing]

I've tried using `colWidths: 200` in the `options` but that only works on everything except row header width.

Options documentation [here](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Options).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4587J/9/)

You can play with the css of columns to set the width:

```
.handsontable col.rowHeader {
    width: 180px;
}
```

And here is a [working example of your case](http://jsfiddle.net/nebj4g56/). If you remove css, you will get exact problem you are facing with. And if you re-add that css line, you will see it works.

Cheers.

Comment: Seems like this is out of date. This did not work for me, but the answer below that uses the rowHeaderWidth parameter does work.

Answer (score 14):

When creating the table in JS you can add the parameter

```
new Handsontable(container, {
    // ...
    rowHeaderWidth: 180,
    // ...
})
```

Comment: The accepted answer did not work. At least this worked. Although, would prefer a CSS way.

Comment: This uses handsontable setting so is correct answer to the Q.