# How to change handsontable row header width?

Tags: css, header, width, row, handsontable

I can't change the width of the row header using the handsontable spreadsheet. 
I've tried the CSS that is referenced in this post: [Handsontable increase row header width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673255/handsontable-increase-row-header-width): From what I've read you can't just use rowWidths like columns but you have to go into the CSS of the row header itself.

```
.handsontable col.rowHeader {
    width: 180px;
}
```

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUhFR.jpg).

CSS is here:

```
html {
    background-color: #e6e9e9;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgb(230,233,233) 0%,rgb(216,221,221) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(270deg,rgb(230,233,233) 0%,rgb(216,221,221) 100%);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em 2em 4em;
    max-width: 800px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #545454;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}


a {
  color: #34A9DC;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0 20px;
}

h4 {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
}


.topcorner {
    position:relative;
        float:right;
        top:0px;
        right:16px;
}

#total {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 2 auto;
    padding: 4em 4em 4em;
}


.handsontable col.rowHeader {
    width: 180px;
}`
```

Here is the JS for the spreadsheet:

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container,
 {
    data: getData(),
    colHeaders: ["Quantity","Cost","Amount"],
    rowHeaders: ["Flights",
                 "Taxi & Bus",
                 "Hotel(nights, cost/night)",
                 "Breakfast & Lunch",
                 "Dinners",
                 "Museum Tickets",
                 "Live Show Tickets",
                 "Driving(miles, cost/mile)"],
    manualColumnResize: true,
    columns: [
      {
        data: 'quantity',
        type: 'numeric',
        language: 'en'
      },
        {
        data: 'cost',
        type: 'numeric',
        format: '$0,0.00',
        language: 'en'
      },
        {
        data: 'amount',
        type: 'numeric',
        format: '$0,0.00',
        language: 'en'
      }
    ],
        colWidths:[80,120,150]

  });
```

HTML div I'm using: `<div id="example" class="handsontable"></div>`

Comment: what do you mean "col.rowHeader"? can you show more your code so i can help you

Comment: Yes, just edited it sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided anywhere near enough information. All I could suggest is that either;

- your CSS is not specific enough and there is not overriding whatever CSS comes with the handsontable library
- your using the wrong selector and therefore the CSS is not being applied.

EDIT: Can you try the CSS below;

```
.ht_clone_left.handsontable tbody tr th { width: 180px; }
```